# (How) can i get django-registration to use the registration_closed template?

Tags: django, django-registration

I have a site goint to betatesting soon. I allready have set up the whole registration process with django-registration, but i do not want to allow external registration right now.

I think i remember a tutorial or description saying that django-registration can be just set to "registration closed", which will then use the registration_closed template instead of the register template. That way the registration cannot be started, and therefore not completed, so the registration would be closed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REGISTRATION_OPEN = False # in settings.py
```

This implies that you are using default backend. If not, you should return `False` in `registration_allowed` method of your backend.

Comment: I knew it was there :)  Thank you.